# Geographic or Zone information

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should we recommend that folks add Zone information to their questions? Better yet, if we can automatically add it (based on their IP address or using their profile) to every question, that would be great.

Comment: Related, [1](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/getting-location-data-from-users), [2](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-should-the-help-center-let-our-users-know-they-should-add-location-data-wher), [3](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/include-geographic-information-in-user-summary), [4](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-to-ask-plant-identification-questions).

Comment: My personal thought is, the most helpful way to do it could be a pop-up prompt when a user clicks the 'Ask Question' link. I feel like using IP would be both inaccurate and invasive.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice. However, people tend to write their location in their profile mostly if they live in a country that guarantees the freedom of thought/expression also in practice, not only in theory (countries from North America, Western Europe, Australia and NZ). Since these are the areas that most users are from, I guess automatically adding location will solve many of our incomplete questions.